# Kohana Auth login with email not username

Tags: kohana, kohana-auth

So as the title says i want to login with my email, not username, now my login works with username, but i can't find a way to change that, so i'm using this basic login code:

```
Auth::instance()->login($post['email'],$post['password'], false
```

**EDIT** After all it was my fault it seems that kohana let's me login using username and email, i had errors in my other script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your login will work with both username and email by default.

If you input a valid email, email field will be compared instead of the username.

Comment: that's strange because it doesn't work, hmm i guess i could try to do that on freshly installed kohana maybe i have some error in different place

Comment: Yeah it worked i guess i have errors somewhere in my ajax scripts